# Needed: A popup window without a taskbar icon

Tags: c++, winapi

I am designing a UI engine that needs to render into popup (WS_POPUP) windows. As these windows cannot be children of other windows, each instance is given its own taskbar icon.

I need a way to prevent the taskbar icons from appearing for certain windows that are created as "dialogs". I cannot use an OS-provided dialog because they all have frames (and I can't figure out how to render into them) or a tool-created custom dialog (which seem to require the CLR).

I am not an expert with the windows API and I feel that I have missed something obvious...

Also: Anything involving CLI/CLR is not an option.

EDIT:

The WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style can be used for this purpose as well, though the activation behavior would need to be emulated by the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set the [WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) extended style for your window, it won't be shown in the task bar or Alt+Tab list. This does cause the window to be rendered slightly differently, however (thinking floating tool palette).